# Does this PDE have a name? $y u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, terminology

I am asked to solve the following equation:

$$y u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0, \quad -\infty < x < \infty, \quad y > 0, $$

together with $u(x,0) = \cos{qx}$ and bounded solution when $y \to \infty$. If I Fourier transform the equation on $x$, I can work a solution to be shown as:

$$ \tilde{u}(y;k) = A_1 \text{Ai}(k^{2/3} y) + A_2 \text{Bi} (k^{2/3} y),   $$  where $\text{Ai}$ and $\text{Bi}$ are Airy functions. If the solution is required to be bounded when $y\to \infty$ then $A_2$ must vanish. The other boundary condition requires $A_1 = \text{Ai}(0) \cos{q x}  $, with $\text{Ai} = 3^{-2/3}/\Gamma(2/3)$.

In order to get the solution for $u(x,y)$, we must anti Fourier transform the solution, $u = \mathcal{F}^{-1} [\tilde{u}(y;k)]  $, which with a little help of WA turns into a complicated expression in function of hypergeometric functions.

Does anyone know a simpler approach? Does this type of PDE have a name?

Comment: This is (closely related to, via a trivial change of variables) the Tricomi equation, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Tricomi_equation .

Comment: maybe, mixed type? it is elliptic in the region $y>0,$ hyperbolic in the region $y< 0$  and parabolic on $y = 0.$